# Rolling Upgrade (with logical standby) from 11g and 19c question

Tags: oracle, upgrade, dataguard

Let's say we have the following upgrade map:

**server1 (11g production db) ---> server2 (11g logical standby db)**

then we upgrade the 11g logical standby db to 19c

**server1 (11g production db) ---> server2 (19c logical standby db)**

Then, the server2 became the new production server. Can Oracle replicate from a high version to a lower version? after server2 became the production server (switchover from 11g to 19c db), we have the following map:

**server1 (11g logical standby db) <--- server2 (19c production db)**

I am asking this because, let's say one week later the application starts to perform poorly, and we need to rollback to the 11g version. Is this feasible? 19c will replicate everything to 11g db version without any problem and we can just switchback to 11g?

Comment: Not sure about dataguard but we did something like this with GoldenGate on a critical system. Was a 10.2 to 11.2 upgrade but we started the replication from old to new system then reversed it to support a mid week backout. We didn't need it but it was working.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with Oracle Logical Standby and different versions, but
From https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/785347_1.html
("Mixed Oracle Version support with Data Guard Redo Transport Services (Doc ID 785347.1)")

> Mixed Version Support to a Data Guard Logical Standby for Rolling Upgrade is supported (starting from 10.1.0.3) over an extended Time Period.

but

> Note that in the supported Cases, the Primary/Source Database is at a lower version, and the Standby/Target Database is at a higher Version.

So it seems that it is not supported to switch the primary from the higher to the lower version.

So you can use it to minimize downtime but not to fall back to the old version.

Comment: "is not supported to switch the primary from the lower to the higher version.". Maybe I'm missing something, but the point of rolling upgrade isn't switchver from o lower version to a high version (after the logical standby upgrade)? and then, upgrade the lower version as well (the old source/primary)?

My question is, if I can leave the source (old primary) in a old version and switchback if I need.

Comment: @Potter Yes, you are right. I wanted to write the converse. I edited the post. So switching back from the new to the old version seems not to be supported.